# TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class CompTable extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        products: [],
        attributes: [],
        attDesc: [],
    };
    this.getEntries = this.getEntries.bind(this);
}

getEntries = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/api/hello/data');
    const body = response.json();
    return body;
};

componentDidMount(){
    this.getEntries()
        .then((resolve) => this.setState({
            products: resolve.products, 
            attributes: resolve.attributes, 
            attDesc: resolve.attributesDescription}))
        .catch(err=>console.log(err));
};


render(){

    let obj = this.state.products[1].attributes;
    console.log(obj);


    return(
        <div id = "comp">    
            <CompHeading comp={this.state.products}/> 
        </div>
    );    
}


}

export default CompTable;
```

The line `let obj = this.state.products.attributes` returns the mentioned error. What's bizzare is that if I remove the ".attributes", the console logs the product object, with the "attributes" property inside it. It seemed like the object just disappeared when I try to access its property XD. Anyone knows the reason why?

Another strange thing is when i remove the ".attributes" the console of my browser logs six objects (though i only call `console.log` once) - 4 of the objects show undefined while the two are the correct product[1] object.

Comment: can you check and revert

Answer (score 0):

Don't trust a console.log, it's not accurate. its value can change. To fix that you can use `JSON.stringify` on the object you are logging to show its real value when you are logging it.

For your problem, you could do something like that :

```
if (!this.state.products[1]?.attributes) return <Loader />
else 
   return (... your content...);
```

This way you will render a `Loader` while you data are not available.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `this.state.products[1].attributes` even before it is populated.

It gets populated from `componentDidMount` which will run after `render` function is done execution.

We need to change the render function variable declaration to this -:

```
let obj = this.state.products.length > 0 && this.state.products[1].attributes;
console.log(obj);
```

So that way it will get value as undefined in the first pass. And in the second pass when `setState` gets called from `componentDidMount` it will get the correct value and your code won't break midway.

Comment: Hey Abhisar. Thanks a lot your code works. Though i still dont understand how adding that length checking part solves the problem because would it still be checking the length of an undefined array? or say if the array are there but not the attributes of the array items, that line would still results in undefined no?

Comment: @kabison33 actually `this.state.products` won't be undefined because it's been explicitely defined as `[]` empty array in constructor which is the very first function that gets executed.

Comment: Please upvote if the answer was helpful... thanks in advance.